# Option Strict On and DBNull.Value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2016

I've started converting an application of mine to use Option Strict On. I've been doing the CStr,Ctype etc, and it's been going well.

```
SQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TERMINATE", If(IsNothing(txtEarningsTerminated.DateValue), DBNull.Value, txtEarningsTerminated.DateValue))
```

Then I hit this. The **txtEarningsTerminated.DateValue** is a custom masked text box. When it's value is Nothing I don't want to store anything in the database. However, it states

```
Cannot infer a common type, and Option Strict On does not allow 'Object' to be assumed.
```

When I change DBNull.Value to "" or nothing, the error goes away. However as Nothing, it fails during runtime stating

```
The parameterized query '(@CONTROL int,@CLIENTCODE nvarchar(10),@NoBill int,@TERMINATE nv' expects the parameter '@TERMINATE', which was not supplied.
```

I want to put a NULL in the database. This value can be a date and then become a NULL.

How do I translate this so as to not produce an error under Option Strict On?

Comment: try setting a default null value in your stored procedure for this parameter.

Comment: `DbNull` is not the same thing as `Nothing`.  No idea what `txtEarningsTerminated` is since it has a `DateValue` property, but I doubt it is Nullable

Comment: txtEarningsTerminated.DateValue is a Date?

Comment: Interesting, when most vb.net developers starts turns `Option Strict` to `On` - C# developers starts more and more using `dynamic` keyword :)

Comment: It took me a little while, but I've changed all AddWithValue to just Add. I also made a program to help with the change. I can't post it here since it isn't related to this question. Now, back onto Option Strict On changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer was obvious and in the error. I just had to encase the DBNull.Value in a Ctype Object

```
CType(DBNull.Value, Object)
```

And then the code would compile just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because operator `If(condition, executeAndReturnIfTrue, executeAndReturnIfFalse)` expects that both `true` and `false` expressions will return same type.
In your case you return `DbNull` type if true and `String`(or some other type you didn't mentioned) if result is false.

If create `SqlParameter` more explicitly, then you can use next approach:

```
Dim value As Object = Nothing
If txtEarningsTerminated.DateValue Is Nothing Then
    value = DbNull.Value
Else
    value = xtEarningsTerminated.DateValue
End If

Dim param As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter With
{
    .ParameterName = "@TERMINATE",
    .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, 'Or use your correct type
    .Value = value
}
```

As mentioned in the comments using `AddWithValue` will force ADO.NET to decide the sql type automatically for your value, which can lead in different problems. For example everytime you run same query with different values your query plan will be recompiled every time you change value.

You can create extension method for `string`

```
Public Module ExtensionsModule
    Public Function DbNullIfNothing(this As String) As Object
        If this Is Nothing Then Return DBNull.Value
        Return this
    End Function
End Module
```

Then use it instead of your "inline If method"

```
Dim value As String = Nothing
Dim param As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter With
{
    .ParameterName = "@TERMINATE",
    .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
    .Value = value.DbNullIfNothing()
}
```

Comment: Just a bit of pedantry, `If()` is not a function but an operator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it (assuming you're using stored procedures in your database):

1. In the stored procedure you're calling, set the date input parameter to equal null, making it an optional field with a default value of null (@terminate DATETIME = NULL).

That way, if you don't include that parameter in your procedure call, the procedure won't fail.

2. Set the default value of the date field to DateTime.MinValue so it always has some value.  Then you can test to see if it is equal to a date other than DateTime.MinValue.  If it is a valid date value, add the line to include the date parameter to the procedure call.  If it is equal to DateTime.MinValue, don't add the parameter to the call.

Comment: The SQL Statement is very small and wouldn't make sense to turn into a stored procedure. In C# I can use null and it works. I'm wondering why I can't do that here?

Comment: @Kayot `AddWithValue` can give problems: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). (And kudos for making your program Option Strict On-compliant.)